# Hostname for WHM account transfer

Tags: hostname

I'm afraid to ask this question, because it seems like it should be something I should know, but I just don't. I'm a reseller of shared hosting for one of the worst hosting companies on the planet, so I want to transfer all of my accounts to another company by means of WHM, using the option "Copy an account from another server with account password."

In order to do that I have to enter the hostname, but what is that and how can I find it? From what I've learned, it usually (or always) has the form "subdomain.domain.com", so I'm almost certain that it's not the URL of the hosting companies site. I could ask them, but I would be lucky to get a response in less than three days, and I don't have that much time. I entered into WHM to look around, and under "Server Information", I found the following line:

```
Linux hd-a5417cl.*********.com 2.6.32-379.1.1.lve1.1.9.5.1.el6.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Sep 3 06:39:55 EDT 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

That "hd-a5417cl.*********.com" looks suspiciously like what I'm looking for, but I want to be sure. I could play around, but before trying to transfer all my client's sites, I'd really like to know what I'm doing.

I know that I can use the DNS, but I don't know what DNS I should use.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [`working with a service provider's management interface, such as cPanel`](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In WHM if you're logged in as root do the following.

Go to "Change Host Name" it will show you the current host name.

---

What you've posted above seems to be the output of uname -a. This command will give you specific information about your system, kernel version, host name, etc.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have root access nor do I have that option in WHM.

Comment: Ok, well either way you've found what you are looking for. What you've posted above seems to be the output of uname -a.  This command will give you specific information about your system, kernel version, host name, etc.

Comment: Thanks for providing that extra information, because when you said "it looks like..." you didn't provide me with the confidence I was looking for. :)